# Get the Node value for the first Node

Tags: java, xml

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<foo>A&gt;B</foo>
```

and just want to get the node value of start tag as `A&gt;B`, if we use getNodeValue it will convert it to A>B which is not needed.

Hence I decided to use the Transformer

```
        Document doc = getParsedDoc(abovexml);
        TransformerFactory tranFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transfor = tranFact.newTransformer();
        transfor.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        Source src = new DOMSource(node);
        StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
        Result dest = new StreamResult(buffer);
        transfor.transform(src, dest);
        String result = buffer.toString();
```

But this gives the following output as part of result as `<foo>A&gt;B</foo>`

It will be helpful if somebody could clarify, if there is an approach with which we can get `A&gt;B` without doing string manipulation from the above output (`<foo>A&gt;B</foo>`)

Comment: Please add tags to identify the language and platform you are using.

Comment: Where is `node` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since getNodeValue() is automatically decoding the the String.
You can use  StringEscapeUtils from Apache Commons Lang to encode it again.

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html
http://commons.apache.org/lang/

```
String nodeValue = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(getNodeValue());
```

That would encode it into the format you want it to be in.
It is not very performance friendly because you are applying encode for every node value.

Comment: Actually, `getNodeValue()` is not decoding the string. The string is decoded when it is parsed. In the information model, which is presumable how it's stored in memory, the string **is** `A>B`, not `A&gt;B`. The latter is just a serialization form. `getNodeValue()` returns the actual string, `A>B`. But the solution given here is correct: if you want an escaped form (`A&gt;B`), you need to ask for it, e.g. using an escape utility.

Answer (score 0):

Actually getNodeValue() is not "converting" the string. 
When the XML is parsed from a file, or produced by a transformation, the resulting information model is that the string **is** `A>B`, not `A&gt;B`. The latter is just a serialization form.

Another legitimate serialization form is `A>B` (because [right angle bracket does not need to be escaped in most cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248958/which-are-the-html-and-xml-special-characters)). However, there may be compatibility reasons for wanting to produce `A&gt;B`, especially if your output is intended to be HTML (though you didn't mention that).

If you have a good reason for escaping the `>`, then I agree with @kensen john's answer for getting that done.