# '&' in password illegal character in web.config file

Tags: xml-parsing, web-config, connection-string

I have a web.config file, in connection string attribute, I have an '&' in password which creates error in parsing web.config file.

code:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>

    <add name="FamefaceDB" connectionString="Data Source=ec2-204-236-162-54.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com;Initial Catalog=famefacedb;User ID=Administrator;Password= t2kfPcn6?D& "/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

The '&' in password is illegal and says hexadecimal value is illegal in XML file.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248958/which-are-the-html-and-xml-special-characters

Answer (score 9):

XML is XML and web.config must be *valid* XML - a "literal" `&` *must* be written as `&amp;`<sup>1</sup>

Compare with the correct entity encoding:

```
<add connectionString="..;Password=t2kfPcn6?D&amp;"/>
```

<sup>1</sup>See [Which are the HTML, and XML, special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248958/which-are-the-html-and-xml-special-characters) (linked by Noel in a comment) for the gritty details.