# Practicing web.config and getting error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am practcing `web.config` file from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301726/Web-config-File-ASP-NET)
when i copy and paste following **code**:

```
<configSections>
  <section name ="ProductSection" type ="<ProductSection" />
</configSections>

<ProductSection>
<gridSettings title ="Latest Products" count ="20"></gridSettings>
<color background="FFFFCC" foreground="FFFFFF"></color>
</ProductSection>
```

I got several **errors** like :

- tag was not closed on second line.
- `</section>` is missing.
- the namespace `'section'` can not include child element.

How to **remove** these **errors** and run it smoothly.

Comment: You should make self assesment before asking on stackoverflow, this is not good question, it can be solved by some googling and searching and understanding the problem.

Comment: @Haider: I am new to .net and came after spending time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
<section name ="ProductSection" type ="<ProductSection" />
```

Try

```
<section name ="ProductSection" type ="&lt;ProductSection" />
```

See [Which are the HTML, and XML, special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248958/which-are-the-html-and-xml-special-characters)

Comment: Thnx for help.
It solved this issue but it says that " An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for ProductSection: Could not load type '<ProductSection'. " Even I edited code like this..
<configSections>
<section name ="ProductSection" type ="&lt;ProductSection" />
</configSections>

Comment: @Sohail: You may have other similar problems i.e. other characters that may need to be escaped. Check the link in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
type ="<ProductSection"
```

This is invalid in XML, get rid of the "<" character:

```
<section name ="ProductSection" type ="ProductSection" />
```

If you actually have something with "<", you'll have to encode it like so:

```
<section name ="ProductSection" type ="&lt;ProductSection" />
```

However as the actual section is `<ProductSection>` it was probably just a typo on your side.