# PHP Generate XML with invalid character?

Tags: php, xml, json

I want to create an xml file that contains invalid characters such as "&", "=" ... etc.

Is it possible because I can not find a solution? Can I convert these characters?

I wonder if it is not better to generate JSON instead?

Comment: Sounds like an XY question to me

Comment: Are you building the XML yourself or using a helper like SimpleXML? SimpleXML should escape everything for you automatically http://php.net/simplexml

Comment: I'm usign SimpleXML like this

`$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
$xml->addChild('team', ('test & yes'))`

But my xml node is not generate

Answer (score 1):

You can include any character in the text "payload" of an XML document. However, as you note, in the case of [special reserved characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248958/which-are-the-html-and-xml-special-characters), you may [need to escape them first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

For example, `&` becomes `&amp;` - short for ampersand, `<` becomes `&lt;` and `>` becomes `&gt;`, less than and greater than respectively. However, as the wikipedia link above shows, `=` does not need to be escaped.

Fortunately, [PHP includes functions that take care of escpaing strings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for you, so I'd recommend just wescaping your text before you add it into the document.

Comment: Thanks, if escpace charcacters everthing is OK !