# PHP: scraping comments in META tags not working

Tags: php, xpath, screen-scraping, meta-tags

I have the following structure:

```
<body>
   <meta name="keywords" content="This is normal text">
   <meta name="description" content="<!--This text is a comment-->">
<body>
```

You would say that scraping with XPath using something like:

```
$meta = $XPath->query ( '//body/meta[1]/@content' ); 
$meta = $meta->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

would return "This is normal text"

and

```
$meta = $XPath->query ( '//body/meta[2]/@content' );
$meta = $meta->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

would return "This text is a comment"

The problem is that the first case works, it returns "This is normal text", but in the second case it returns nothing, as if there was no text.
Any idea what is wrong here?

What I need is the text tagged as comment ("This text is a comment").
Would appreciate your help.

Comment: As you quote:- "but in the second case it returns nothing, as if there was no text." If there was no text then It will return no text

Comment: I have tried your code and it give me perfect <!--This text is a comment--> for 2nd meta tag. your 2nd meta tag contains <!--This text is a comment--> not <!--This text is a comment-->

Comment: the point is that in my real life example, there is text... I thought that maybe because the text is tagged as a comment, it is not readable...

Comment: Shubham, I have found an example you can test with, just as a way of having a real example and not have just a theoretical case.

http://www.entornointeligente.com/articulo/6871898/Paraguay-negocia-con-firmeza-con-Argentina-por-binacional-Yacyret-01092015

Search for the META tag where name = "description" and try to get the content, which is tagged as comment.

Answer (score 0):

An attribute cannot contain a comment. Your problem is actually that the XML is not valid:

> ```
> <meta name="description" content="<!--This text is a comment-->">
> ```

The attribute here starts with a `<` character, which must be escaped using an entity reference, like `&lt;`. Since it isn't, parsing this as XML should result in an error. In fact, this is not only invalid XML, it also [invalid HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248958/which-are-the-html-and-xml-special-characters). The link you gave, [doesn't even get passed the first character](https://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.entornointeligente.com%2Farticulo%2F6871898%2FParaguay-negocia-con-firmeza-con-Argentina-por-binacional-Yacyret-01092015), btw.

The fact that PHP returns nothing here surprises me. It uses `libxml` under the hood and that should have raised an error here. You didn't say how you scraped the HTML. If you are using some scraping tool that converts it to XML, it is very well possible that the scraper changes the object model to make it valid XML. To find out whether this is true, inspect the result of the expression `meta[2]` as XML fragment, perhaps it removed the invalid attribute, perhaps it placed the comment as a child to `<meta>`, in which case you can get to it with `meta[2]/comment()`.