# Solr difference between '<' and &lt;

Tags: solr

This I have in my solr schema file

```
<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s\?\!\:\;\,\(\)\\\*\'#\$%\-\/\=\@\[\]\^\_\{\}\|\~&quot;&lt;&gt;]"/>
```

Solr play good with breaking such text

```
Hello&lt;World&lt;!
```

But fails with this

```
Hello<World>!
```

There is no results with the query `World` but a lot of with `<World>`

How can I rewrite the pattern to break on the `<` symbol also?

I try CDATA, but it is not working

```
<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s\?\!\:\;\,\(\)\\\*\'#\$%\-\/\=\@\[\]\^\_\{\}\|\~]|(&quot;|&lt;|&gt;|[CDATA[<]])"/>
```

and a little modified pattern

```
<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s\?\!\:\;\,\(\)\\\*\'#\$%\-\/\=\@\[\]\^\_\{\}\|\~]|(&quot;|&lt;|&gt;)"/>
```

same not working for me

**UPDATE**

Solution

```
pattern="[\s\?\!\:\;\,\(\)\\\*\.#\$%\-\/\=\@\[\]\^\_\{\}\|\~&quot;&lt;&gt;«»]|(&amp;lt;)|(&amp;gt;)"
```

Also works without change my first pattern turn on html filter in schema that is converting `&lt;` to the `<` and solr parses `<`

```
<charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about the [solr.PatternTokenizerFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/pattern/PatternTokenizerFactory.html). You want to split at '<'. This is a question about how to escape '<' in xml.

Your first approach is correct

```
<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s\?\!\:\;\,\(\)\\\*\'#\$%\-\/\=\@\[\]\^\_\{\}\|\~&quot;&lt;&gt;]"/>
```

as you can read her: [Which are the HTML, and XML, special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248958/which-are-the-html-and-xml-special-characters)

so please search for your problem with

```
Hello&lt;World&lt;!
```

via [analysis screen](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Analysis+Screen).

Comment: analysis screen awesome